# Stored procedure not as defensive as it looks

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have several stored procedures structured like the following:

```
USE [WHouse]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_Alert_Dly]
AS
    IF (SELECT LastRunDate FROM WHouse.dbo.AlertRunDates WHERE NameDescription = 'X' ) < (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
    BEGIN
       --================
       --need to comment the following out if trying to re-run
       UPDATE x 
       SET  x.LastRunDate = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
       FROM WHouse.dbo.AlertRunDates x
       WHERE [NameDescription] = 'X' 
       --================

       --===============
       --DO A LOAD OF STUFF IN HERE 
       --INCLUDING USING DB_SENDMAIL TO EMAIL 20 PEOPLE
       --===============

    END
```

My colleague has set up a reporting system (using procedures / SSIS) that loops every 10 minutes and as long as a stored procedure completes without an error then it is marked as complete in a control table.

What I don't understand is even if the above throws an error why would it ever repeat the section between `BEGIN / END` more than once in the same batch ?

If it is not defensive enough how do defend against my colleagues system causing the same emails to get distributed every 10 minutes?!

Comment: Possibly an outer transaction was rolled back or aborted? You can roll back the update but you can't roll back the e-mails that were sent. Maybe use a queue table and a background process instead of actively sending the e-mails immediately.

Comment: Sending emails from a proc seems like a risky proposition to me anyway. Can't you solve this in the application code?

Comment: @usr well if it's Database Mail it's asynchronous (utilizes service broker), so the only risk really is that you can't roll it back. :-) That said, I do agree with you. These e-mails should be sent elsewhere (whether it's a background process in SQL Server, or external altogether).

Comment: @usr when you say "application code" are you referring to my colleague's StoredProcs/SSIS process that is running this stored procedure every 10 minutes?

Comment: @AaronBertrand +1 thanks....how do I make sure that the `UPDATE` in the script does not roll back? Aslong as `UPDATE x SET  x.LastRunDate = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())` is successful then the next time the proc is run it will never get past `IF`; but it is as if when the proc fails the `UPDATE` is not happening. I'd like o make my code defensive enough to avoid having to worry about changing my colleague's process

Comment: @AaronBertrand this sounds good "Maybe use a queue table and a background process instead of actively sending the e-mails immediately" .... I realise you are probably very busy - are you able to give me this with some extra detail in an answer?

Comment: If this is running as part of a SQL job I'd consider setting up a step that uses [BLAT](http://www.blat.net/) in a batch file to fire off an alert, then wouldn't need to worry about the transaction state potentially firing off multiple alerts.

Comment: @DarthContinent - thanks but I'd rather keep things simple

Comment: @AaronBertrand what exactly do you mean by "background process"?

Comment: @whytheq e.g. a job running from SQL Server Agent

Comment: @AaronBertrand - ok so have a table "EmailQueue" that has fields such as `Body`,`TO`,`CC` and then the (not much experience using the agent) agent somehow checks that table and if it sees new entries it will run a sproc to build and send the mail using DB_SendMail ?

Comment: Agent would run a stored procedure that checks the table for new entries, send any e-mails it needs to, then mark the entries as processed. Sometimes the stored procedure would be run by agent, but not have anything to process. That's ok. There are other ways to do it (e.g. service broker) but Agent is by far the simplest.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks for the info - this is effectively my answer; copy/paste it into an answer and I'll mark it so.

Comment: Glad to help, but feel free to self-answer when you've worked out the specific details of your implementation.

Comment: @AaronBertrand if I added a trigger to the table `EmailQueue` and the trigger runs a DBSendMail script, would this be effectively the same as creating a background process with the agent ?

Comment: Then it's not really a queue table ... You're back to the initial transaction having to wait for the trigger(s) to complete. You've just added an additional table for no reason. What is so hard about creating an Agent job?

Comment: @AaronBertrand +1 thanks - I'd also researched and come to the same conclusion - I'm currently working on the original solution you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately scrapped the pattern in the OP and have used the suggestions put forward by Aaron in the comments of the OP i.e created a `EmailQueue` table and set up a background process that loops every 5mins (via the `Agent`). This process scans the `EmailQueue` table for any new records and sends out emails if required.